# include ("x.php") gives a undifined variable error

Tags: php

Actually I don't know how to ask this question.
I have two pages one is reservation.php and roomdetail.php .
reservation.php is all about getting checkin,chekout,roomype,facility types from user. 
roomdetail.php is a filtrate of the database according to the selection option made on reservation.php

I am showing the room details on same page(reservation.php) after submit the form which is in the reservation.php..

submitting are working as I expect. But my problem is when I load reservation.php at first time it shows

```
Notice: Undefined variable: roomdetail in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bridgeview/UI/availableroom.php on line 80
```

I dont know how to solve this problem.please guide me

Comment: maybe duplicate but can you please read the body sir.. thanks for advanced

Comment: are you define roomdetail  variable on availableroom.php ?

Comment: mam as its says error variable its not defined but called.

Comment: u can do something like `if(!empty($roomdetail))` and then call your variable code.

Comment: availableroom.php page line 80 roomdetail is called without defining. define roomdetail variable in that page

Comment: May be the roomdetail is not defined in your code. Try using **if(isset($roomdetail) && $roomdetail!='')**

Comment: Ya I assigned variable roomdetail in reinstall.php

Comment: Advice: Don't define a variable in file A.php and access it in file B.php. Better use design patterns which allow you to keep the scope clear and don't mix dependencies.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave thanks sir.. its working perfectly

Comment: Welcome mam (bow)

Comment: for any issue, u can email me at mittulphp@gmail.com i will help you to solve there directly.